# How to fix an aborted 12.04 upgrade?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, upgrade, dual-boot, trackpad

I was upgrading to 12.04 when my computer froze up then crashed. It was about two thirds of the way done installing when the crash occurred, and the wireless network wont work and the track pad on my laptop no longer functions... How do I repair/finish installing the new OS version? I dont want to have to delete then reinstall the OS. 
Ps. im dual booting with windows 7.

Comment: Fresh installation would be better option under these conditions, try to backup your data using Live Installation media.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the Ubuntu CD, and run the installation as if its a new install.  When you get to the Installation type screen, you may choose: Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.04,

[image].

I don't have the exact image, but this will help you get the idea.  In you case it will be ***Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.04***

Hope that this will help you in your quest.